Ошибка (ConnectionError: [Microsoft][¶8A?5BG5@ 4@0925@>2 ODBC]) при подключении к mssql через node.js (npm mssql)
Создал обычную базу данных в SQL Server. Ничего лишнего просто пустая бд.

Затем подключил npm пакет mssql (npm install mssql msnodesqlv8). Делал всё строго как описано в документации. Вот код:

Вместо подключения выдаёт такую ошибку:


[Microsoft][Диспетчер драйверов ODBC] Источник данных не найден и не указан драйвер, используемый по умолчанию. Посмотрите внимательно на конфигурацию подключения - в адресе сервера желтым подсвечено, что буковка S экранируется.
